# Finitely generated ring with zero Krull dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Every finitely generated ring with Krull dimension equal to zero is finite.

I'm trying to show that the ring is a domain, hence a field, in order to use the property that   claims that every finitely generated field is finite, but I'm not seeing how I can show that this ring is a domain, so I guess that this way may, may be not the best way to show this.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What notion of finite generation are you using that excludes infinite fields?

Comment: What do you mean by a finitely generated ring that is finite?

Comment: @Benja: presumably it means finite as a set.

Comment: @Charles: the ring is not necessarily a domain, e.g. a finite product of finite fields works.

Comment: @rschwieb: finitely generated as a ring.

Comment: It seems you can use the fact that since your ring is finitely generated Z algebra that it is Noetherian. But, Noetherian and dimension zero is equivalent to Artinian. Decompose your ring into the product of local Artinian rings, and go from there.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand the example, thank you!

Comment: Dear @QiaochuYuan thanks for voicing the obvious speculation. Please In the future let me draw it out of the poster, and save your time for something worthwhile. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see this, note that since $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, that it is necessarily Noetherian. Thus, $R$, being Noetherian and dimension zero, it is necessarily Artinian. Thus, we have a decomposition of $R$ as $R\cong R_1\times\cdots\times R_n$ where each $R_i$ is a local Artinian ring, which is necessarily also finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

Now, it suffices to show that each $(R_i,\mathfrak{m}_i)$ is finite. It is a common fact that a local Artinian ring with finite residue field is necessarily finite itself. But, note that $R_i/\mathfrak{m}_i$ is a field which is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, and so necessarily finite (this follows by the Nullstellansatz).

Comment: Why the down vote? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the $R_i$ are not necessarily finite fields, e.g. they may have the form $F[x]/x^n$ where $F$ is a finite field. This doesn't seem too hard to fix though.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I somehow made a stupid mistake! Fixed

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you!

Comment: @AlexYoucis I just don't understand why R beeing finitely generated, implies that R is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra?

Comment: @Charles What is the ***definition*** of a finitely generated ring?

Comment: @BenjaLim oops I see it now! Sorry for the silly question! Thank you!

Comment: @BenjaLim It has to mean finitely generated as a Z-algebra

Comment: @BenjaLim: For every algebraic category there is the notion of (finite) generating systems, therefore of finitely generated objects.

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, I posed the question to the OP simply because he was not sure why $R$ being f.g. implies that it is f.g. as a $\Bbb{Z}$ - algebra. Regards,